# How to print or transform np array of 240*240*4 as 240*240*1?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, python-imaging-library

I am looking for something where I just want to print the first channel of the np array.

Original size = 240*240*4
Target size = 240*240*1 (only the first channel.

I tried, below but does seems to be working.

```
image[:,:,:1]
```

But saving back with size 240*240*1 to png or jpg doesn't work

Sample code

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import scipy.misc as sp
image = np.array(Image.open("FLAIR-148.png"))
test_image = image[:,:,:1]
sp.imsave('out.png', test_image)
```

output

```
File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/misc/pilutil.py", line 327, in toimage
raise ValueError("'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for "
ValueError: 'arr' does not have a suitable array shape for any mode.
```

Comment: Just slicing works.  image[:, :, :1] yields an array of size 240 x 240 x 1.  Are you really using a matrix, or is this a numpy array?

Comment: @tnknepp So if image of size `240, 240, 4)` converted to `image[:, :, 1]` and then if I try to save it back to png or jpg, will it allow me to save? because I tried doing it and it gives me error.

Comment: I don't know, but I don't see why this would fail either.  Can you post some example code (minimal working example)?

Comment: @tnknepp updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you  don't slice the last index (ie do `image[:, :, 1]`) then everything should work fine:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import scipy.misc as smc

image = np.array(Image.open("FLAIR-148.png"))
test_image = image[:, :, 1]
smc.imsave('out.png', test_image)
```

Basically, `scipy.misc.imsave` does't know what to do with an array of shape `(M, N, 1)`. However, it does know that it should save an array of shape `(M, N)` as a grayscale image.

You may also need to convert the array to `uint8` to ensure consistent results. Here's a complete minimal example:

```
import scipy.misc as smc

# get the test image as an array
img = smc.face()

# slice test image
img = img[:, :, 1]

# convert to uint8
img = img.astype('uint8')

# save
smc.imsave('test.png', img)
```

Output:

[image]

## Caveat

[`scipy.misc.imsave` is deprecated](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imsave.html#scipy.misc.imsave). It is suggested to use [`imageio.imwrite`](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imwrite) instead.

Comment: `img = smc.face()[:, :, 1]` where should I give the parameter of image for slicing?

Comment: I've edited my answer to make this line clearer (I split it into two lines). `smc.face()` returns an array of shape `(768, 1024, 3)` that represents an RGB image of the raccoon. The square brackets (and the code in between) `[:, :, 1]` is the slice.